# I can't go back to previous activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have one activity A that launch an Activity B. In this activity I have a button that launch an activity C and this activity has a save button. When I press the save button or the back button in the phone, the activity C is finish and go to the Activity A. I want that go to activity B, but I don't know what is happening.

Thanks is advance.

This is the intent that launch activity C from B.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(B.this, C.class);
       intent.putExtra....
.
.
.                       

startActivityForResult(recordIntent, REQUEST_DATA);
return;
```

This is the save button:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.menu_save) {
String displayString = editName.getText().toString();
    ServiceCall.upload(this.name, true, displayString, id);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you overriden `onActivityResult()` in `B`?

Comment: It's not clear from the information you have provided why you are calling "startActivityForResult" and passing recordIntent rather than intent. Generally speaking unless you need Activity C to explicitly return something, then use startActivity(intent) instead. I can't see any code on the R.id.menu_save handler that would cause the activity to end.

Comment: Is there any chance you post your Manifest as well?

Comment: We will need the code of the three activities in where you make the intents to go through the activities. We will need the overriden method that you have about back button, for example.

Comment: Please very ServiceCall.upload  method has some code to redirect to activity A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to come back to the right activity: only use this line before the `finish()` method

```
startActivity( new Intent(this, YourActivity.class) );
```

And to press the back button and return to the activity that you want:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    startActivity( new Intent(this, YourActivity.class) );
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This is solving my problem partially. But the activity "B" is just relaunched and hence the information I wanted to return from activity "C" is still lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you try save the instance state?